# IIS with Windows Authentication and session id in url unreliable

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, iis, asp.net, windows-authentication

We use Windows authentication for an ASP.NET application that also uses cookieless sessions, so the session id is encoded into the URL.  If the users login via the root url, no problem.  But they also save the application to their bookmarks using a url which includes the session id, and after this session expires, the site returns a 401 error which can never be satisfied.

To avoid this, we added a 401 redirect to the base url, and this works for a while.  But eventually, possibly after a restart (we don't control restarts on this server), Windows authentication stops working completely.  The users are shown a login pop-up, and this never succeeds.  We have to delete the 401 redirect, login at the base url, then restore the redirect.  Now the application works properly again.

I get the impression that we are doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.  The 401 redirect in particular feels like a hack, but I can't think of another way to allow old sessions to redirect back to the application to get a new session.